# CDA HL7V3 acknowledgement

Tags: mirth, cda, hl7-cda, hl7-v3

I create using Mirth a channel that receives CDA messages in HL7V3 format.
I'm able to parse the message and extract all  the data i need.
My question is: How do i create an acknowledgement to the receiver?
I found out that there is a message called MCCI_MT000200UV01 that i need to implement but i can't find good explanation and/or examples.

I have been working a long time with HL7V2 and the acknowledgement  is very simple.
Can't find a way to implement this in HL7V3 format.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide some of the code you are using and the one failing. Maybe your working HL7 v2 code will also help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about a generic Accept Acknowledgment message which is MCCI_IN000002UV02 (according to the HL7v3 NE2014). If I were you, first thing to do I'd download the HL7v3 Normative Edition that matches the year of your inbound message used to transport the CDA document (unless it's HL7v2). Then I'd go to HL7v3NE > Specification Infrastructure > Messaging > Transmission Infrastructure > Generic Message Transmission and find the Accept Ack interaction. There is a related XML Schema that allows you to build an XML template for the v3 ACK (XMLSpy like tool does that by default).

Since ACKGenerator does not support HL7v3, next step is to create a code templates function that builds the v3 ACK from the template you acquired from the previous step.

(PS. The whole procedure with samples is explained in an "Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer's Guide" available at mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com)

Comment: I've just checked, the Accept Acknowledgement that uses MCCI_MT000200UV01 message type was published up to NE2012. Later versions of the standard are using next version of this message type.